# Testing AppCompatActivity toolbar with FragmentScenario.EmptyFragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-fragmentscenario

For my test I launch the fragment in an emtpy activity root view container

```
@Before
fun init() {
    scenario = launchFragmentInContainer(null, R.style.Theme_AppCompat) {
        MyFragment()
    }
}
```

and in my fragment, I configure the toolbar to provide back button

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

so when I run my test I get a class cast exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$EmptyFragmentActivity cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```

so I have to add a gaurd

```
if(requireActivity() !is FragmentScenario.EmptyFragmentActivity)
    configureToolBar()
```

so is there another way to configure the toolbar so that I can test the back button intent launch with espresso?

**edit**

Apparently there is a way to create a custom activity/container.

Comment: What **fragment** behavior are you verifying in your test when you say "is there another way to configure the toolbar so that I can test the back button intent launch with espresso?" - it seems that any espresso test you would be doing there would be verifying the activity, not your fragment.

Comment: I want to verify back navigation from the fragment.

Comment: So what code **of your fragment** is running when you test the up button in your Toolbar? That logic is on the Activity, which isn't what you're testing if you're using `FragmentScenario`.

Comment: you can have toolbar inflated in the Fragment layout and set it as support toolbar by `AppCompatActivity`. Additionally custom handling of up button can be done in the fragment which should be testable with `FragmentScenario`